# SSRS Report using SSAS cube - time calculations

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, cube

I am looking for optimized solution for the below problem -

I have a cube which contains Date dimension which has one hierarchy month->quarter->year.

I have created a cube, all good. Now my ssrs report requires all my dimension customer sales attributes along with the calculations like 
last month profit, 
current month profit, 
last 6 months profit (listing every month), 
last month transactions, 
last year profit vs current  year profit.

As i have created a hierarchy all my calucations for every month and every year and every quarter already pre-calculated in the CUBE. Now to retrieve the above listed calculations, what is the best way to do these time calculations? Where to put these calculations in CUBE or in the SSRS DATASET?

Could you please suggest some good approach and how to do it?

Comment: i don't know .your question is for formula Of those calculated field or . where to put this calculate (cube or dataset)..?

Comment: wher to put and how to do it? could you please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's certainly possible - if you're comfortable with MDX - to write your query to get all these calculations into your dataset, it's usually better for reusablity across many reports to put these types of calculations in the cube. That way, other tools can also use the time calculations if you decide to use Excel or a 3rd party application.

You can use the Business Intelligence Wizard from the Calculations tab to do this - here's an article for SSAS 2005 that's still applicable to later versions: http://www.obs3.com/pdf/A%20Different%20Approach%20to%20Time%20Calculations%20in%20SSAS.pdf

And here's another approach to do something similar:
http://www.bidn.com/articles/mdx-and-dmx/169/mdx-time-calculations-done-the-right-way

UPDATE: 
For named sets to handle date ranges like the last 6 months from now, see this article: http://my.opera.com/duncans/blog/using-custom-sets-in-analysis-services-to-deliver-special-date-ranges-to-end-use

Comment: Thanks Stacia for your kind answer. it is useful. But still I have got few queries - 1. how to include all the time calculations like YTD, LAST SIX MONTH CALCULATION INDIVIDUALLY, LAST 13 MONTHS calculation in the same cube. Sorry I may be asking a trivial question but I am not clear of this concept. I have a cube with a time dimension. Now I would like to have a calculation in DimDate which will give me last 6 months calculations seperately so that when I create a dataset from this cube I can drag this calculated field to my report which can display last 6 month calculations? could you please

Comment: If you read the instructions I provided, it will explain how you can do this. The Business Intelligence Wizard can set up calculations like that for you and you can modify it from there. Some people like to make the calculations part of the Date dimension, and others prefer a separate dimension as described in the links. You really need to try it and see in a prototype cube for YTD, etc.

Comment: As for Last Six Months or Last 13 Months, you need to create a named set which is separate from a calculation. A calculation like YTD is a value that you display a single column. When you need a list of months (6, 13, 24 or whatever), you need a named set which is a list of members. That's a bit trickier and I have to leave for a while. I'll post a solution later today.

Comment: I have a question for you before I dive into this. Are you looking for the last 6 months from now (the day that you're looking at the report)? Or the last 6 months from a date that you drag into the pivot table?

Comment: Thank you Stacia, I will look into the named set. That clears my confusion now :). Could you please guide me about named sets like last 6/12/13 months and how to use them in SSRS reporting - in dataset? In one of my report I got to show last six months profits by individual month and also in another column i need to show YTD values. How can I develop this? I need to use named set and also ytd calculation right? Would be great if you can show me some articles ro provide some guidance? ****Yeah I as looking for last 6 months from now***** Many thanks for your support

Comment: Ok - that's a bit easier. Here's an article that should help: http://my.opera.com/duncans/blog/using-custom-sets-in-analysis-services-to-deliver-special-date-ranges-to-end-use

Comment: Thanks Stacia, you saved my life time of atleast 1 week :). calculations are working great now, I am looking into the named sets now.

Comment: Hi, I got a query in the named sets. I created a named set TwoYearsRolling- CREATE DYNAMIC SET CURRENTCUBE.[TwoYearsRolling]
 AS [Date].[Year].&[2010]:[Date].[Year].&[2012];    It is acting as a filter while creating a dataset in SSRS. That is fine. But I would like to display year 2011 and 2012 measures (profits/losses/margins/netloss/etc..) individually in different columns. Year 2011 & Year 2012 in columns and measures in the rows. Could you please guide me how to do that? what need to be applied to the column groupings? Can I apply these named sets in column grouping?

Comment: Hi Stacia, Could you please look into this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425562/ssas-cube-time-calculations-named-sets    With your helpful comments I have progressed well but I am stuck with another problem as in the link. Could you please comment on that? Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I get you, but the problem is that you need to get dynamic values and you have everything hard-coded?

You can get the previous member in a hierarchy with the prevmemebr function:

```
([Date].[Calendar].PrevMember, <your measure here>)
```

where date is the dimension and calendar is the hierarchy.
So if you are browsing by month, it will get the last months data for example

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate  last month profit, current month profit, last 6 months profit as measures in the cube 'calculations' using mdx query. I recently did this for my 'revenue comparison report' where I calculated`last month's revenue`, `last2monthsrevenue` and `priorquarterrevenue` and used them. It worked!